# Save Excel file locally using client object model and C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, csom, file, save

I have a scenario where I have been able to get the file that I want to download using a CAML query. I am using client object model approach. I need to save this file locally. Please guide how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Based on my research and past experience this could be an approach to download files from a SharePoint Document Library.

First you get connected to the SharePoint site, and retrieve using `list.GetItemById(ID)` function.

Once you load item object, you can get the `Server Relative Url` of the file. And from this Url you can download the document.

You can read [How to download/upload files from/to SharePoint 2013 using CSOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057074/how-to-download-upload-files-from-to-sharepoint-2013-using-csom)

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
{

    var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    var listItem = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
    clientContext.Load(list);
    clientContext.Load(listItem, i => i.File);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    var fileRef = listItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
    var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef);
    var fileName = Path.Combine(filePath,(string)listItem.File.Name);
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
    {                  
        fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```